# Query for documents where match contiguous array elements

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with documents in the following format:

```
    { "_id" : 1, "tokens": [ "I", "have", "a", "dream" ] },
    { "_id" : 2, "tokens": [ "dream", "a", "little", "dream" ] },
    { "_id" : 3, "tokens": [ "dream", "a", "dream" ] },
    { "_id" : 4, "tokens": [ "a" , "little", "dream" ] },
    ...
```

I need to get all doucuments which "tokens" include contiguous array elements: **"a", "dream"**.
So, the following are matched  doucuments:

```
    { "_id" : 1, "tokens": [ "I", "have", "a", "dream" ] },
    { "_id" : 3, "tokens": [ "dream", "a", "dream" ] },
```

Is there a way to get the right results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick that is to have a regexp.

- `$match` to get the all documents which has `$all` array input
- `$addFields` to have a duplicate the tokens and input array
- `$reduce` helps to concat all string joining `-`
- `$regexMatch` to match both strings
- `$match` to eliminate unwanted data
- `$project` to get necessary fields only

The code is

```
[{
    $match: {
        tokens: { $all: ["a", "dream"] }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        duplicate: "$tokens",
        inputData: ["a", "dream"]
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        duplicate: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$duplicate",
                initialValue: "",
                in: { $concat: ["$$value", "-", "$$this"] }
            }
        },
        inputData: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$inputData",
                initialValue: "",
                in: { $concat: ["$$value", "-", "$$this"] }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        match: {
            $regexMatch: { input: "$duplicate", regex: '$inputData' }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        match: true
    }
}, {
    $project: {  _id: 1,  tokens: 1 }
}]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mQinUZsECj6)**

Note: Do check multiple scenarios although its working for this scenario